# BigCommerce API. What is the syntax of an url string that would allow me to download orders in xml?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

BigCommerce API. What is the syntax of an url string that would allow me to download orders in xml? 
Can I embed the login credentials in the string and post as https get or do I need to post them as xml?
I have tried different variations of username, api_key, api_toke and inserted them in the url string but I keep getting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: **No, you cannot** send your credentials in the URL. It's doubtful that such a thing would retain the PCI compliance of your store.

You would need to send your user credentials (username and API key) via HTTP headers with something like CURL. Technically you can do this with AJAX but thats a huge security risk so you have to process the request server side.

If you want to test if you can actually make a connection ***try this***: http://www.hurl.it/

**URL:** site_url/orders.xml
**GET**
**HTTP Basic Auth** ->
 
**Username:** Bigcommerce username
**Password:** API Key

This should return a result.