# REST Interacting with BigCommerce from VB EXCEL

Tags: vb.net, rest, bigcommerce

NOTE: Further research (and thick skin, and lots of coffee) has lead me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552731/bigcommerce-api-what-is-the-syntax-of-an-url-string-that-would-allow-me-to-down?rq=1) where it suggests that the store cannot receive the uid and pwd in the URL, and I gather from the PHP examples [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/quickstarts/php) that the transmission needs to be encrypted. Is this my problem? If so I have not been able to find anything on how to work around this.

I would be happy if the open() command prompted the UID & PWD window to open and I can manually input the values. Does anyone have a suggestion. Thanks!

---

I am learning how to use the BigCommerce APIs and I am programming in VB / XL to be able to directly post / retrieve from all fields in the store's DB.

I have never coded on this before (although I get around VB OK) and I am stuck. I have the following code:

```
Const URL As String = "https://www.myurl.com/api/v2/brands.json"

Public Sub Test()
    Dim xmlHttp As Object

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False, "myid", "mytoken"
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

    Range("A1").Value = html.body.innerHTML

End Sub
```

What I get back is "401" or more precisely:

```
[{"status":401,"message":"No credentials were supplied in the request."}]
```

The credentials are valid and working, as if I place the URL in my browser and submit it, the pop up for UID & PWD comes up, and once I place the values I am using in the code, the resulting BRANDS list appears in the browser.

Additionally, if I add a "rand num" to the URL to ensure the returned data is not cached as suggested [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), then the request looks like this:

```
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL & "&t=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 99), False, `"myid", "mytoken"`
```

and the response back from BC changes to:

```
406</STATUS><MESSAGE>The requested content type is not available.</MESSAGE></ERROR></ERRORS>
```

I have also tried this (where UID and PWD are the correct values):

```
xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL & "&user=UID" & "&password=PWD", False
```

and i get:

```
406</STATUS><MESSAGE>The requested content type is not available.</MESSAGE></ERROR></ERRORS>
```

Can anyone help me understand pls. I have followed examples at MSDN, but I am still stuck. The BC API site is poor in examples (none actually!) for VB.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorted! BC required this:

```
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL_Cat, UID, PWD
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(UID & ":" & PWD)
xmlHttp.send
```

I got Base64Encode code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/base64-encode-string-in-vbscript). Hope this helps someone.